# Web.config. Redirect all traffic to www.my... Using rules element.

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config

I have a web.config file which automatically sends traffic to HTTPS. However, if someone enters in MyDomain.com then it will go to https://mydomain.com and if someone enters www.mydomain.com then it will go to https://www.mydomain.com.

I want ALL traffic to go to https://www.mydomain.com. Is this possible using the rules element of the web.config? My file currently looks like this:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
      <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
      </rule>
  </rules>
```

Comment: Anyone? Alternatively, advice on how do it using the IIS GUI would be great as well.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## The Rule

```
<rule name="Redirect to www subdomain">

  <match url=".*" />

  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" negate="true" />
    <add input="{SERVER_PROTOCOL}" pattern="^(.*)(/.*)?$"/>
  </conditions>

  <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>

</rule>
```

## Explanation of Rule

- `<match />` Limits a rule to only requests whose path and query string match the given pattern. In our case we want to match all paths and query strings since we will redirect based on domain.
- `<conditions />` Limits a rule even further to just the matched requests that satisfy the given conditions. The first condition excludes requests whose domain already starts with "www". The second condition is there just for the {C:1} backreference and it shouldn't filter out anything.
- `<action>` prepends "www." to the domain and then redirects.

## Variables

- `{R:0}` is a backreference to the full match from the `<match \>` tag. The back-reference should only contain the path and query string since that is all that `<match \>` ever matches against.
- `{C:1}` is a backreference to the first match group from the final condition. This should contain everything up to the "/" in the {SERVER_PROTOCOL} variable.
- `{HTTP_HOST}` is a server variable that contains the requested domain. (See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for a full list.)
- `{SERVER_PROTOCOL}` another server variable. Its format should be "{protocol}/{version number}".

## Other Options

- `<action redirectType>` can be Temporary, Found or SeeOther. (See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx) for more info.)
- `<conditions logicalGrouping>` can be MatchAll or MatchAny.

## Conclusion

For a more complete explanation please see [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference).

Comment: Do we add that rule or replace the posters?

Comment: Thanks you so much! I would ask how could you keep this, redirects like a champion monkey! BUT not redirect IF the domain contains ie: "bypdm.com" those are temp urls we use to show the client and they don't have a www setup in IIS?

Comment: Wouldn't you want `redirectType="Permanent"` for a 301 redirect?

Comment: @ajbeaven This would also work. However, google would rank you down because it wouldn't be a "Permanent".

Comment: @Luke Huh? Using `redirectType="Permanent"` (as apposed to the `redirectType="Temporary"` used in the answer) would make it a 301 permanent redirect, so Google won't rank you down at all.

Comment: @ajbeaven Oh! Opps sorry that was my bad. I'm sure I saw it as temporary. :(

Comment: @Mark Rucker well explained.. :)

Comment: Just a heads up, on Microsoft-IIS/10.0 I had to change the `{SERVER_PROTOCOL}` match pattern to `^(.*)(\/.*)?$` (i.e. had to escape the `/` character). This puzzled me for a while, so hopefully this'll prevent someone else waiting half an hour.

Comment: The use of `{C:1}://` didn't work for me, this made the rewrite append the entire url as a querystring `mywebsite.com/HTTP/1.1/://www.mywebsite.com` if i switched it to hardcode a http protocoll the rewrite worked properly