# web.config redirect non-www OR non-https to https://www using rules

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config

I need to redirect all non-www or non-https traffic to `https://www` using rule in web.config

```
http://domain.com --> https://www.domain.com
http://www.domain.com --> https://www.domain.com
https://domain.com --> https://www.domain.com
```

I modified rules from [Web.config. Redirect all traffic to www.my... Using rules element.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893284/web-config-redirect-all-traffic-to-www-my-using-rules-element) but it fails to redirect `http://www.domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com`.

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Redirect to www subdomain">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{SERVER_PROTOCOL}" pattern="^(.*)(/.*)?$"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer, i think it would help others if i post it here.

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Redirect non-www OR non-https to https://www">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" />
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 4):

This will redirect all non www or non https to https://www

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="non-www-https to www https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
    </rule>

  </rules>

</rewrite>
```

I added this line to ignore it on IIS express (local host):

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
```

The other advantage of this is that you do not need to enter your domain in this rule.

You can read more here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/redirecting-non-www-to-domain-equivalent